# How to migrate documents with metadata to another site collection

Tags: document, metadata

Environment: SharePoint 2013

How to migrate documents with Metadata and Content types to another site collection?

Comment: I guess you have gone through this thread http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125006/how-do-i-move-sharepoint-lists-and-libraries-to-another-site-collection here also the requirement is same as you

Answer (score 2):

If you can use PowerShell than there is one ready to use PowerShell commands mentioned in below mentioned article.

[How to Copy SharePoint Documents Between Site Collections Using PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rcormier/2012/11/16/how-to-copy-sharepoint-documents-between-site-collections-using-powershell/)

Comment: Hey Jason, Is above answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

You can try third party tools as there are many tools available in the market. These tools are very good for content migration along with item permissions and other functionalities.

Some of them are:

1. [Metalogix](http://www.metalogix.com)
2. [Avepoint](http://www.avepoint.com)
3. [Sharegate](http://www.share-gate.com) (It is giving 15 days trial also)
4. [Metavis](http://www.metavistech.com)

Answer (score -1):

You can also try [LepideMigrator for Documents](http://www.lepide.com/lepidemigratordocuments/sharepoint-to-office-365-migration.html) it works very well while migrate documents with Metadata and Content types to another site collection.

However, if you want to move the contents of a SharePoint Document Library or List and be able to preserve the item’s metadata/property values at the same time you should use this method:

Create a blank destination List or Document Library. Don’t have to worry about recreating custom fields and whatnot. The move process will do this for you.

Then go to the ‘Site Content and Structure’ page. You can access this site with either Site Actions > Site Settings or http://portal/_Layouts/sitemanager.aspx

After that navigate to your source List or Document Library and mark all the items that you would like to have moved. Then click on Actions > Move

You’ll then be prompted with a pop-up that will let you navigate to your destination List or Document Library. After you find that, just press the OK button and you’ll be good to go!

Also you can move files between document libraries programmatically using PowerShell or by using SharePoint designer, get in detailed here: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/06/move-files-between-document-libraries-with-metdata-version-history.html

Hope this helps!