# Created by User not retained when importing a document library

Tags: 2010, document-library, move

I have a SP2010 Farm that is running 2 Site Collections.  The server is on a domain which has a trusted relationship with a second domain.

I need to move a site from one site collection to the other.  I have done this using the stsadm commands to export the site from collection one and import into collection two.

However, when I look at the site in collection two, some of the documents are retaining their modified user details and others are being replaced with system account.

It appears that documents created by users that are on the older domain (same domain as the SharePoint server is linked to) are correctly showing the created by user.  Documents that were created by users linked to the second new and trusted domain are importing and being linked to System Account.

It appears that the second site collection does not see link the users on the trusted domain.

Any idea how I can rectify this so that future imports link the users correctly?

Answer (score 0):

[How do I move SharePoint Lists and Libraries to another Site Collection?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125006/how-do-i-move-sharepoint-lists-and-libraries-to-another-site-collection)

Above question is similar to what u have asked and should solve ur issue..