# How do site owners move lists between team sites in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

As a site owner, how would I move a list between two sites? The "save as list template" option doesn't appear in the list settings which is where most of the guidance points to.

Comment: Is it SharePoint Online or OnPremise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way does not exist anymore, save as template used to be a life saving option but not available now, you can hack the URL and get to site template page but lists created through template may not work properly.

few options are discussed [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125006/how-do-i-move-sharepoint-lists-and-libraries-to-another-site-collection)

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate any lists or libraries from source(2007,2010,2013,2016,Online) to SharePoint online by migration tools. you can easily migrate them with out loss of any property or data.

here is one of the migration tool. you can download free trail version. this free trail can do your complete list or library with out any problem.[Migration tool Download](https://en.share-gate.com/download)

you have to specify the organization email. Yahoo or gmail won't work for free trail registration.

Answer (score 0):

The general steps are:

Save the source site as a template

Then attach the saved template to the destination site in SharePoint Online

Copy the content from source site to the destination site in SharePoint Online

Get in detailed here: http://expert-advice.org/2017/01/migrate-sharepoint-online-different-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365-tenants/

Comment: That is a site-level transition, I was just looking for a list-level transition.